# How to await in a method returning list?

Tags: c#, methods, windows-phone-8.1, async-await

i have a static method that should return list. but i want to do an await inside the method.

```
public static List<ContactModel> CreateSampleData()
    {
        var data = new List<ContactModel>();
        StorageFolder musiclibrary = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
        artists = (await musiclibrary.GetFoldersAsync(CommonFolderQuery.GroupByAlbumArtist)).ToList();


        for (var i = 0; i < artists.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {

                data.Add(new ContactModel(artists[i].Name));

            }
            catch { }
        }

        return data;

    }
```

when i make it

```
public static async Task<List<ContactModel>> CreateSampleData(){//method contents}
```

i get error on another page for this code

```
Error: Task<List<ContactModel>> doesnt contain a definition for ToAlphaGroups

                var items = ContactModel.CreateSampleData();
                data = items.ToAlphaGroups(x => x.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to await your async method:

```
 var items = await ContactModel.CreateSampleData();
```

Your method now returns a Task, thats why you get the error message.

Comment: that code is inside a methode i can't add async to  public IList Data
        {
            get
            {
                if (data == null)
                {
                   
                    var items = await ContactModel.CreateSampleData();
                    data = items.ToAlphaGroups(x => x.Name);
                }
                return data;
            }
        }

Comment: isnt there a way i can await inside a method and at the same time it return list?

Comment: Whats the use of using async/await if the calling method runs synchronously? If there is no synchronous version of GetFoldersAsync you'll have to run GetFoldersAsync synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether I should mention this because I agree with the answer of [Jan-Patric Ahnen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148569/how-to-await-in-a-method-returning-list/36148770#36148770).

But since you said you cannot add `await` to your code: `Task` has a property called [Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) that returns the "result" of the Task.

```
var items = ContactModel.CreateSampleData().Result;
data = items.ToAlphaGroups(x => x.Name);
```

A few things before you use `Result`:

- `Result` blocks the calling thread, if called from the UI thread your app might become unresponsive
- You should try to avoid `Result` at all cost and try to use `await` since `Result` can produce unexpected results.

Comment: i added result but as you said the app became unresponsive in debug and crashes in normal launch

Comment: yeah, expected that to happen somewhere